# How do I find the combined Hilbert space for this Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I knew that the operators in the folwing Hamiltonian act in different Hilbert spaces, so I cannot just multiply them.

$$\eqalign{
  & H = g\left[ {\left( {a\sigma _1^ +  + {a^\dagger }\sigma _1^ - } \right) + \left( {a\sigma _2^ +  + {a^\dagger }\sigma _2^ - } \right)} \right]  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\, + J\left[ {\left( {S_1^ + \sigma _1^ -  + S_1^ - \sigma _1^ + } \right) + \left( {S_2^ + \sigma _2^ -  + S_2^ - \sigma _2^ + } \right)} \right] \cr} $$

How do I find a combined Hilbert space for this Hamiltonian?

Comment: It's usually the tensor product of the smaller Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Please can you provide more details for me? I cant apply this to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the types of operators denoted by $a,\sigma$, and $S$ each act on separate Hilbert spaces $\mathcal H_a,\mathcal H_\sigma,\mathcal H_S$. Then your Hamiltonian should act on $\mathcal H:=\mathcal H_a\otimes \mathcal H_\sigma\otimes\mathcal H_S$, and the operators it's made up of should act like
$$a(\vert\psi_a\rangle\otimes\vert\psi_\sigma\rangle\otimes\vert\psi_S\rangle)=(a\vert\psi_a\rangle)\otimes\vert\psi_\sigma\rangle\otimes\vert\psi_S\rangle,$$
and similarly for the other operators. Basically, each operator only acts on the corresponding part of the state.